# Solving logarithmic equation without calculator

Tags: logarithms

I was wondering if it possible to correctly determine the solution for the following logarithmic equation to precision of one decimal point without a graphical calculator:

$$30\log_{10}(t)+t-72=0$$

Thank you

Comment: Is this your homework ?

Comment: you can draw some pictures yourself. On paper. This increases with $t,$  and $t=10$ is too small. $t=100$ is too large.

Comment: This equation cannot solved algebraically. So use an approximation method. Are you familiar with the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), for instance?

Comment: No, it's from a set of exercises for exam preparation; there no similar exercises in the textbook. I looked up for a way with Tylor expansion, by this is way beyond our level, also I don't know to deal with the error...

Comment: next $\sqrt{1000} \approx 31.62277$ gives $30 \cdot \frac{3}{2} + \sqrt{1000} = 45 + \sqrt{1000} \approx 76.622$  Suggest using rational $\delta$   with very small denominator  and try $10^{1+ \delta}$   as well as $10^{2-\delta}$ In effect, move the problematic logarithm term to estimating $\sqrt[3]{10000}$ and similar.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no easy answer by hand.

Comment: $ 30 x + 10^x = 72$ seems a bit better, with this $1 < x < 2$

Comment: Thank you, guys!

Comment: @WillJagy After observing that $10\sqrt{10}$ is close, rewrite the logarithm as $\log t = \log\frac{10\sqrt{10}}{10\sqrt{10}}t = \frac32+\log\frac t{10\sqrt{10}}$. From there, using the approximation $\log x \approx \frac2{\ln{10}}\frac{x-1}{x+1}$, which is good when $x\approx1$, we have $$30\left(\frac32+\frac2{\ln{10}}\frac{\frac t{10\sqrt{10}}-1}{\frac t{10\sqrt{10}}+1}\right)+t-72=0.$$ This is just a quadratic, and with the well-known approximation $\ln 10 \approx 2.3$ we get a very accurate $t\approx28.4$.